# Bodeplot of a differential equation using a fourier transform in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a second order differential equation which I want to transform to the frequency domain using a fourier transform from which I can create a bode plot using matlab.

I have transformed the equation by hand already, but I can't seem to find documentation on how to get the bode plot going. The bodeplot accepts a laplace transform functions from what I have read.

So my question is, how can I define a function in the frequency domain in order to create a bode plot with said function?

Another thing I am curious about is how I can take a differential equation in matlab and transform it into the frequency domain using fourier?

The differential equation is attached below.

[image: Differential equation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Laplace transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) to get the transfer function from the differential equation:

```
Y(s)/X(s) = 1/(10*s^2+0.1*s+1)
```

In MATLAB, this is defined easily (you need the Control System Toolbox) with the [`tf`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) function:

```
H = tf(1,[10 0.1 1]);
```

and then you can use the [`bode`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/bode.html) function to get the bode plot:

```
bode(H)
```

[image]